# Recording sound using android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, record, mediarecorder

I'm trying to record sound by creating an android application.
here is the code:

This is the helper class

```
package com.recorder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

public class AudioRecorder {

final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
final String path;

/**
* Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
*/
public AudioRecorder(String path) {

    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
  }

  private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
    }

    return Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }

  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
}

/**
* Stops a recording that has been previously started.
*/
public void stop() throws IOException {
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
}
 }
```

and this is my activity:

```
package com.recorder;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecorderActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    ImageButton mic;
    private AudioRecorder recorder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     recorder = new AudioRecorder("/Mysounds1");//here is the path
    //to sdcard where we will save the recording
    }
    // Action listener for a button which record sound   
         public void mic(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Recording started...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
        recorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I run the code I get the following exception:

java.io.IOException: SD card is not mounted. It is removed.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to emulate the sdcard also. GO to AVD --> Edit --> in SD card slot, give any number to emulate that amount of memory as sdcard. Done

Comment: the problem was sloved.. but now I get new exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException /Mysounds1 (permission denied)

Comment: it means the file is not present in your emulated sdcard. Push your file into the sdcard and it should work. Also check for the file from FIle EXplorer of DDMS.